# How to log exception using autoretry in Celery tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, django-celery, celery-task

From celery documentation,

```
If you want to automatically retry on any error, simply use:

@app.task(autoretry_for=(Exception,))
def x():
    ...
```

How do we log the exception that it retried for?
It would easy to add a log if we have a try-except, for example

```
@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30 * 60)  # retry in 30 minutes.
def add(self, x, y):
    try:
        something_raising()
    except Exception as exc:
        logger.info('Retry for exception %s', exc)
        # overrides the default delay to retry after 1 minute
        raise self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=60)
```

but I want to use autoretry so I can make use of celery's retry backoff that comes with autoretry and not implement my own countdown with try-except. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Add **throws** argument while declaring task, this will pop the exception on the screen and it can be changed to any expected exception you want to throw. For example RequestException, TimeoutException

```
@app.task(bind=True, throws=(Exception,), default_retry_delay=30 * 60)  # retry in 30 minutes.
def add(self, x, y):
    ...
```

Comment: According to this documentation https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#Task.throws expected exceptions will *not* log the stack trace.